# What are backing types?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, types, assemblies

I don't quite understand what the mean by this (MSDN):

`XAML directly represents the instantiation of objects in a specific set of backing types defined in assemblies. This is unlike most other markup languages, which are typically an interpreted language without such a direct tie to a backing type system.`

What is a backing type and backing type system? Are these sets file where tags for the XAML are defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Backing Types` here just means that there are specific, direct equivalent classes that match your XAML declarations. Your XAML is the markup - but the WPF assemblies have exactly matching classes that "back those up".

This is as opposed to HTML; your web browser probably doesn't have a class named `img` to match your `<img>` tags. It actually might; but HTML is not meant to represent distinct, backing types. XAML, on the other hand, is *meant* to have a 1-to-1 relationship between its object tags and actual classes in code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What role do they play in the parsing/compilation process, how it would be different if there was no backing types? I mean why do we have them?

Comment: The role the backing types play is that they must exist and be able to use the attributes and values defined in the XAML, just like in traditional 'code', the type names you use must exist and the properties/methods you call must be correct.

Comment: Why do we have them? They are what implement the functionality of WPF. XAML is simply one way you have of coding WPF. You can do it with straight C#/VB.NET, too. But you are always using the WPF classes to do so. Tying the backing types to the defined XAML tags makes it much easier for you to go back and forth between code/markup and know what is happening.

Comment: Thank you again. So straight C#/VB.NET also use the backing types, they are just different means of writing instructions. Once the code has been parsed, the gencode is built by hooking up the parser to the backing types? I've mostly done theoretical CS and Math and am trying to wrap my head around the process.

Comment: I'm not qualified to nitpick the exact terminology here, but you have the idea; You could picture that the parser is taking your valid XAML and converting it to code, which you could have written in C#/VB.NET/etc too. XAML tends to be more clear for defining the interface.

Comment: So when I write code in say C#, the compiler uses the backing types, my question is if the backing types are not only meant for XAML?

Comment: @mihajlv Those types can be created and used without XAML, yes. XAML is just a primary way to create and configure them in code, but you could write a WPF program completely in C# or VB.NET, creating those same types.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, XAML is a language for describing the instantiation of an object tree and setting of various properties.  As such, it's very closely related to the CLR and its type system.  It's extremely powerful and it's used extensively by WPF, though there is nothing preventing you from using it for other types of object trees.

XAML is made 'WPF specific' by using this namespace definition:

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

This tells the XAML parser that the default namespace should be as defined above, which then maps to all of the various WPF class types.  This URL is defined by the various assemblies that contain WPF-specific types by defining one or more XmlnsDefinitionAttribute on each assembly, mapping the various assembly namespaces to the XML namespace.

---

For additional information on the meaning of XAML, see [XAML Syntax In Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx).  There is also a link there to the XAML language specification.  It's worth noting that XAML is a compiled language, the product of which is a .NET class that can be instantiated.  It is a language that is designed for efficiently describing deeply nested and complex content, with property value assignments and addition of elements to collections, which can be awkward to do from C#.  The XAML compiler does support code-behind, however, which allows you to associate additional C# code with the class constructed by the XAML.

Comment: Thank you. So in essence the namespace defines all the tags for the XML which are derived from the backing types.

Comment: @mihajlv, yes, the XML namespace effectively maps to one or more .NET namespaces.  You can then instantiate any public class from those namespaces with a parameterless constructor by entering its class name as an Element in the XAML.  Classes that support 'Content' can have additional elements included underneath them, which either sets a property to contain the Content or adds the Content to an underlying collection.  The details are well-documented by MS and worth perusing if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you, can I know what documentation you are referring to?